# Scrollable HTML Table in Vertical and Horizontal Option

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a table which has many columns and lots of records.  My user want me to have the table to have a fixed header but should have a scrollable option in both the vertical and horizontal version?

Is this possible to do this that is cross browser?  My target browser is IE 6.0 + and FF.

I am looking for a CSS version or jQuery version solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed header with pure CSS is impossible: [HTML fixed header table scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338758/html-fixed-header-table-scrollbar/)

To scroll your table look here: [CSS fails to create a horizontal scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337841/css-fails-to-create-a-horizontal-scroll-bar/3337900#3337900)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting `overflow:scroll` on css. Something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow).